# Don't Append if the same in jquery

Tags: jquery

table1 has contents ( items ) while table 2 has nothing ( because it is the shopping cart ) now what i want to do is to check if the user is adding the same item on the shopping cart and if he/she does it will add the qty and doesn't write another tr. How can i do this?

```
#table 1
<table>
  <tr><td>Item001</td><td>5.00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Item002</td><td>5.00</td></tr>
</table>

#table 2 //it is blank because it will be filled later via onclick from table1
<table>
</table>
```

if the user clicked item001 it will be appended to table2 now if the user selects item001 again it must not write item001 again on table2 but will only append the quantity.

### UPDATE

```
var itemDesc = $(this).find('.desc').text();
var getPrice = $(this).find('.price').text();
var itemName = $(this).find('.itemName').text();
var currentId = $('#cartGrid tr').attr('id');

if(itemName == currentId)
{ 
    qty +=1;
    $('.tableQty').html(qty);
    qty = 1;
}
else{
    $('#cartGrid').append("<tr id="+ itemName +"><td>" + itemDesc + "</td><td class='tableQty'>"+ qty +"</td><td class='tablePrice'> $" + getPrice +"</td></tr>");
    
}
```

Now i got it to work. But only on the first item. Help? THank you

Comment: Well, we need something more than this. What about some code or something?

Comment: Are you holding all of the shopping cart items in a JavaScript object and passing that variable, or are you independently querying the server for each object?

Comment: all items are retrieved via restful web service.

Comment: There needs to be at least a unique ID to do a comparison between items existing in Table 1 and items existing in Table 2. If not, and you know the text of the item will always be the same, you can compare the text string by matching it with jQuery. The rest of the idea is to perform an 'if' statement declaring that if the item exists increase the value of the items added to the cart by 1.

Comment: but i want it to put on a onclick event. how would that be? can you give me a sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code a bit to get it working:

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qmVHr/

// HTML

```
<table class="items">
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Item001</td><td>5.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Item002</td><td>5.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="shopping-cart"></table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

// JS

```
$(function() {
  $('table.items td.name').click(function() {
    var itemName = $(this).text();
    var $addedItem = $('#' + itemName);

    if ($addedItem.length) {
      var qty = parseInt($addedItem.find('.qty').text());

      $addedItem.find('.qty').text(qty + 1);
    } else {
      $('<tr id="' + itemName + '"><td>' + itemName + '</td><td class="qty">1</td></tr>').appendTo($('table.shopping-cart'));
    }
});
```

You didn't post the complete code, but it seems like your problem is in this part:

```
qty +=1;
$('.tableQty').html(qty); // this will update all the rows in your shoppingcart grid, not just the one you want
qty = 1; // not sure why you put 1 here, but this will always set the updated qty to be 1 + 1
```

Comment: yes, it worked. i actually removed qty = 1; i realized that it is causing the problem to. thank you.

Comment: Hi, i would just like to ask what does $added in your code means? Thank you.

Comment: When an item or row is added to the table.shopping-cart, I add the item name as the id of that row.  $addedItem is to basically fetch the row based on the id.  If there's anything returned ($addedItem.length > 0), then that means the item has been added to the table.shopping-cart before.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not so good with jquery but this may give you an idea i think:
http://jsfiddle.net/w39MV/2/

I'm using click function for every item, when we click an item it checks it's id in basket with `.length` if exists show us error message else clones item into basket with `clone()` and `appentTo()`